# MySQL select distinct in subquery with exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with about 500k rows and I want to remove duplicates. First I run  select distinct to see count of unique rows:

```
select distinct f1, f2, f3, f4 from my_table;
```

And it returns me about 300k rows.

I want to insert unique rows into another table, so I run next query:

```
insert into table_unique 
    (select * from table where exists 
        (select distinct f1, f2, f3, f4 from my_table)
    )
```

But this query inserts me all rows, not only unique ones. It looks like select distinct is working a bit strange in subquery.

Can anyone explain me this behavior?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `select distinct` in the subquery is meaningless.  The `in` already, essentially, removes duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Select distinct` query does indeed return one copy of each row.

However, your `select * from table where exists` returns all records that match those distinct rows, thus returning all copies, as well.

Comment: Thanks, I understood now. So it look for me like the only way to do what I need is to use `select in` instead of `exists` and `group by` instead of `distinct`

Comment: Years late, but for other readrs: **NO** you don't need in or group by at all.   You do not need the exists query to achieve the result, omit it. i.e.  `insert into table_unique     
select distinct f1, f2, f3, f4 from my_table`

Answer (score 0):

Does 'table_unique' have only the columns you distinct by from 'my_table'?
If you just want to insert the unique values, you don't need 2 nested select statements:

```
insert into table_unique     
select distinct f1, f2, f3, f4 from my_table
```

If there are more columns, you'll have to tell the SQL server how to transform the data - specify aggregate function, or MAX/MIN, or whatever.

In this case `GROUP BY  f1, f2, f3, f4` should be added after the select statement